# TexStudio Latex inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:¬† not set up for use with LaTeX

Tags: biblatex, texstudio, unicode

I think my Latex bib file is corrupt and so I always get the error message for Line 177 (which is directly after printing the bib):

```
Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8: not set up for use with LaTeX.
```

In the log file there is some more information and the symbols are displayed:

```
inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:¬† not set up for use with LaTeX
```

However I searched through my latex file and could not find the error. How to find the part where \u8:¬† is created?

Thanks.

Comment: you have quite an old latex, the format of the message is different in current releases. You have only shown a fragment of the error message the final line will be of the form `l.88 ¬†`  if the error is detected on line 88

Comment: I just updated my latex version by installing the newest MacTex and now it works. no more error messages. thanks for pointing in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

updating to the newest version (MacTeX-2021) did the trick. I'm not sure if the error is solved or the error can now be handled, but a least all my references are created and my bib looks fine.